# Migrate existing content types to MongoDB

Tags: entities, database, migrations

I have a "Company" content type that has about 30 fields that I'd like to migrate over to MongoDB (field_sql_storage to mongodb_field_storage).

Would anyone know of a great way to do this?

I have about 150,000 nodes and it's starting to get slow in MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - you want to use the Migrate module to map your fields from a datasource (ex. CSV file) into your new MongoDB. Moshe [has a post](http://cyrve.com/mongodb) on this, more related to performance of his method for Amazon RDS but there is an example module that extends the Migrate API to pull the data from a CSV file into his MongoDB database. The relevant [include file is here](http://drupalcode.org/project/migrate.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/migrate_example_baseball/migrate_example_baseball.migrate.inc) (maybe a little to long to include on stackoverflow?).

To get your data out of the content-type into a csv dump, I would recommend using [Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export).

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.  I guess I was hoping for something easier, but I can see why the full migration is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal's mongodb module has built in support for migrating fields. Here is a detailed post by chx on how to migrate fields on a live site with drush to mongodb  https://drupal.org/node/1653202